# Post numpy array with json to flask app with requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Using Requests, I need to send numpy arrays with json data in a single post to my flask application. How do I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To convert a numpy array `arr` to json, it can be serialized while preserving dimension with `json.dumps(arr.tolist())`. Then on the api side, it can be parsed with `np.array(json.loads(arr))`.

However, when using the requests `json` parameter, the dumping and loading is handled for you. So `arr.tolist()` is all that is required on the client, and `np.array(arr)` on the api. Full example code below.

Client:

```
params = {'param0': 'param0', 'param1': 'param1'}
arr = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data = {'params': params, 'arr': arr.tolist()}

response = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

API:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    data = request.json
    params = data['params']
    arr = np.array(data['arr'])
    print(params, arr.shape)
    return "Success"
```

Output:

```
{'param0': 'param0', 'param1': 'param1'} (10, 10)
```

Note: When either the `files` or `data` parameter is being used in `requests.post`, the `json` parameter is disabled.

Comment: This has incredibly low performance for large arrays.  A much better way (at least 50% lighter) is to use tostring() and fromstring()

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer gets the job done for small arrays but has incredible low performance for large arrays (At least 150% of overhead).

I would recommend using tostring() instead of tolist().

EDIT 2023: .tostring() has been replaced with .tobytes() - both returns a copy of the raw data (much more efficient than sending a text representation of the array).

So client would become:

```
params = {'param0': 'param0', 'param1': 'param1'}
arr = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data = {'params': params, 'arr': arr.tostring()}
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

And API:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    data = request.json
    params = data['params']
    arr = np.fromstring(data['arr'],dtype=float).reshape(10,10)
    print(params, arr.shape)
    return "Success"
```

You should note that the shape and dtype of the array must be known beforehand or informed in the request body.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because arr.tostring() returns bytes, which is not JSON serializable, so requests.post throws an error. What is the solution for this?

Comment: You can also, encode it in base64:
arr = base64.b64encode(np.array([1,2,3,4]).tobytes()).decode('utf-8')
# arr = 'AQAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAA='
vec = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(arr),dtype=int)
# vec=[1,2,3,4]

Comment: encoding is a brilliant idea! my work is possible standing on the shoulders of giants.