# How to send an array as response to client in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask. I wonder how to use Flask to send an array from server to client. Here is my test code. For some reason, client is not able to convert the received data back to array. Can someone shed some light on this please? Thanks.

Client:

```
import numpy as np
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_array = np.arange(10000)
    data = pickle.dumps(my_array)

    url = "http://192.168.1.150:5000" + "/test"
    response = requests.post(url=url,
                        data=data,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})

    buf = response.content
    my_array = np.load(buf) # fails on this line
```

Server:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    if request.content_type == "application/octet-stream":
        data = request.get_data()
        nparr = pickle.loads(data)
        
        # do something w/ nparr here

        # send an array to client
        my_array = np.arange(10000)
        buf = BytesIO()
        np.savez_compressed(buf, my_array)
        buf.seek(0)

        return send_file(buf, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='a_file', mimetype='application/octet-stream')
```

Comment: Presumably `np.load` is not the opposite of `np.savez_compressed`. What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: You're probably going to be better served converting the array to a list using `array.tolist()` and then having requests serialize it as json in your post request using `requests.post(url, json=my_array.tolist())`. Then you can de-serialize on the server and convert it back into a numpy array, avoiding any weird issues with pickling/versioning/etc.

Comment: Have you tried to use `response.raw` instead of `response.content`?

Comment: mkrieger1, this is the error I got. "File "C:\Users\BlueStar\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 416, in load
    fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 17: invalid start byte". If I use response.raw instead, I will get a different error.

Comment: Stephen, requests.post(url, data=pickle.dump(my_array)) works fine. The problem is with the response from server to client. Using array.tolist() will lose the shape of the array, right?

Comment: You can have a look at this SO answer , maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548127/post-numpy-array-with-json-to-flask-app-with-requests